# Find position of element in react when CSS is using overflow: scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How would you find the position of an element while you are scrolling if you have CSS on the parent div of overflow: scroll? I am using hook like this

```
const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
  console.log(scrollPosition);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const position = window.pageYOffset;
    setScrollPosition(position);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
```

This works when the parent div has no overflow property in CSS, but when i have overflow on it just always says 0.

Trying to make it so that when a div gets to the top of the page, i want to change it to almost act like a header - like how spotify web app works with their playlist header.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `window.pageYOffset` shows the scrollbar position of the document body. You should be looking for the scrollbar position of the parent element instead.

Below there's a hook which you can use to get the scrollbar position of any HTML element. It attaches an event handler for the scroll event which tracks the element's `scrollTop` property.

```js
import { useState, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

export default function useScrollBarPosition() {
  const [top, setTop] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    function getTopPosition() {
      const topPosition = ref.current.scrollTop;
      setTop(topPosition);
    }
    ref.current.addEventListener('scroll', getTopPosition);
    getTopPosition();
    return () => ref.current.removeEventListener('scroll', getTopPosition);
  }, []);

  return [ref, top];
}
```

Then apply it to your element like this:

```js
import useScrollTop from './use-scroll-top';

function FooComponent() {
  const [ref, top] = useScrollTop();
  console.log(top);

  return (
    <parent ref={ref}>
      <child parentPosition={top} />
    </parent>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use position: sticky for header
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position